# I am trying to define a new Function with object properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to define a function as part of an object and using the same object properties, but I get the error 'SyntaxError: Arg string terminates parameters early'

```
let x = {};
x.str = 'Hello Wor\nld';
x.a = /\s/g;
x.action = new Function(x.str, x.a, 'return ' + x.str + '.replace(' + x.a + ', "")');
console.log(x.action);
```

Comment: `Hello Wor\nld` seems like a rather odd thing to name a function parameter. so does `/\s/g`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All but the last argument to `new Function` should be the *parameter names* (which must be valid variable names) - they can't have a space in them, or be a regular expression. For example:

```
new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b')
```

results in something like

```
function(a, b) {
  return a + b
```

Similarly, what you're doing currently:

```
function foo(Hello Wor
ld, /\s/g) {
  // ...
```

is invalid syntax.

Make a function which accepts no arguments instead:

```js
let x = {};
x.str = 'Hello Wor\nld';
x.a = /\s/g;
x.action = new Function('return `' + x.str + '`.replace(' + x.a + ', "")');
console.log(x.action());
```

Note that because `x.str` is a string, you should enclose it in string delimiters, and that since it contains a newline character too, you should enclose it in backticks.

Better yet, don't use `new Function` at all:

```js
let x = {};
x.str = 'Hello Wor\nld';
x.a = /\s/g;
x.action = () => x.str.replace(x.a, '');
console.log(x.action());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I assumed I was making a silly mistake. The reason for using the new function is that the function inside could be different. e.g. 'find' instead of 'replace'. An object will have the expression for the function that will be created.